# How can I animate Angular Material 2 dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can I animate Angular Material 2 dialog?

I tried using the normal Angular 2+ animation theory. it works, but what happens is the elements on the dialog get animated (as expected), and the dialog simply stays. But what I want is the dialog itself should animate, for example, the opacity should go from 1 to 0 in a couple of seconds.

I also checked whether the `MdDialog.close()` method has any options to animate, but there seems nothing.

Animating the opacity of a dialog from 1 to 0 (before closing it for example) is a common use case, how can I achieve it with Angular Material 2 dialog?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available yet. You can track the status [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8857).

Answer (score 0):

The dialog should be animating by default as seen [here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). Did you include `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your app?

Comment: I want to make a custom animation, for example, the opacity should go from 1 to 0 in a couple of seconds.