# Modify the animation of an angular 2+ material dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How do you modify the animation of a dialog in Angular 2+ ?

I need to make it display with a diffirent animation then the one from the animation library but i dont want to do that without disabling the default animations for other components ?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331324/how-can-i-animate-angular-material-2-dialog. An issue is opened to handle this, but it is not available yet.